# Working with same class elements in a table

Tags: jquery, html-table

I want to set the width of `th` the same as `tbody td` if their classes match. I tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
$("#table th").each(function(i){
    var ClassName = $(this).attr('class');
    $(this).width( $("#table tbody td" + ClassName).outerWidth(true));
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not how you generate a class selector. This is:

```
$("#table th").each(function(i){
    var ClassName = $(this).attr('class');

    // replace spaces with '.'s
    var classSelector = '.' + ClassName.replace(' ', '.');
    $(this).width( $("#table tbody td" + classSelector).outerWidth(true));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
$("#table th").each(function(i){
    var ClassName = $(this).attr('class');
    $(this).width( $("#table tbody td[class*=" + ClassName + "]").outerWidth(true));
});
```

You need '.' for class selector.

Also note that attr('class') returns all the applied classes, which may be more than one, so you need to prefix each with '.'

Comment: And if there are multiple classes?

Comment: The post was edited right before your comment, but good notice!

Comment: `td ." + ClassName` will select a child element of the td, but we need the td width

Comment: I edited one more time to apply for the TD and not for children.